# Why use "drive out of their way"?

Tags: grammar

I was doing some reading and saw a sentence, which is "Often it became more time-efficient for drivers to drive out of their way on Interstate than take a shorter but less speedy local route."

I don't understand why it uses "drive out of their way". It sounds like giving way to others, but it means to stay on the Interstate. I think they should use "drive their way on Interstate", instead.

Can anyone explain it to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *go out of your way* is an idiom meaning 'to take a longer route than necessary to reach your destination'. We speak metaphorically of 'going out of your way to help someone', which can mean, not just that you step aside from your route, but that you put yourself to inconvenience.

In the context of your quotation, the drivers were using a route that meant travelling a longer distance, but on faster roads so that it took less time than the direct route.

Comment: Maybe add that a map would show the faster route is longer *in distance*, though drivers know it's shorter in time.

Answer (score 0):

"Their way" there could be understood as their most direct (and therefore the shortest) route.  They can take a route that is indirect (over a greater total distance) but speedier.

They might have to drive  miles in a direction that is not towards their intended destination in order to reach the interstate  highway. But once on the highway they can easily make up for that delay by driving much faster than they could drive on the local route, which might be congested with traffic and have cross-roads with traffic lights where they could have to wait for a green light, possibly several green lights, before  they can proceed again.